# Java HttpClient error

Tags: java, request

When I try to send a POST request with an HttpClient to a website which uses CloudFlare, I don't get the website page content.
It looks like I get "blocked" from CloudFlare.
How can I get a solution?
This is the code I use:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://website/");
// Request parameters and other properties.
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "Bob"));
try {
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    // writing error to Log
    e.printStackTrace();
}
/*
 * Execute the HTTP Request
 */
try {
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity respEntity = response.getEntity();

    if (respEntity != null) {
        // EntityUtils to get the response content
        String content =  EntityUtils.toString(respEntity);
    }
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // writing exception to log
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // writing exception to log
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What is the actual error, exception, response?

Comment: @dotvav I get an error which says that I can't navigate to that Website, it says me this error: https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171936-Error-520 , Cloudflare is a service to prevent DoS/DDoS attacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check and make sure you are sending required parameters in your request and try adding user agent in your request :

```
params.add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0");
```

If you really want to check which parameters are being sent in request when you are doing it from browser, one way I know is to use Firefox extension Tamper Data. It will show you all parameters of header and post data and will allow you to modify them also.

Answer (score 0):

check your server not blocked post requests in ([CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)) by default

Comment: It's not my server, but in C#/VB.NET I can make the request without any problem